# first 'roscore' and a question arrises- like i'm 5

Tags: ros, roslaunch, catkin, roscore, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

~beginner decrypting the workings of ROS~
hmm.. how to phrase this.. well, partly, I'm wondering

1. if I need to also be in my catkin workspace before roslaunching...
2. what is the difference between the catkin and roslaunch?
3. I understand that the catkin is like a framework/build system basically for package management??
4. So now that I'm learning about nodes, I'm wondering, how is the node different from a catkin built package?
5. How are roslaunch and associated tools, different from catkin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269540/first-%27roscore%27-and-a-question-arrises--like-i%27m-5/) by [moonspacedancer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31680/moonspacedancer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2017-08-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-24**:
There's a lot of questions here... Have you gone through the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials)?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-24**:
I edited your question to make it a bit easier to see all the questions.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-25**:
I think that the [Getting Started](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Introduction) pages might be more suitable for a first introduction, especially when the questions are more of a [conceptual nature](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Concepts).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-25**:
@binarybabe: it might be helpful for you to go get a book or two about ROS. Some are even free. See [wiki/Books](http://wiki.ros.org/Books). A good one is probably: [A Gentle Introduction to ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/Books/AGentleIntroductiontoROS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. No, you don't need to be in your workspace to run `roslaunch`, you can `roslaunch` from anywhere.
2. `catkin` is used to create and build packages and `roslaunch` starts up nodes, sets parameters, etc.
3. As @gvdhoorn pointed out in the comments, catkin

> is a wrapper around CMake that makes building entire ROS *workspaces* easier / feasible. Package management is expressly not part of its responsibilities.

4. A node is a program and a `catkin` package is a place that houses nodes and certain files.
5. See #2.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-25**:
@jayess: no, catkin is not a framework for package management. It is a wrapper around CMake that makes building entire ROS *workspaces* easier / feasible. Package management is expressly not part of its responsibilities.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-25**:
@gvdhoorn: thanks for pointing out my error. I updated the answer based on your comment.